# How to pass Express response object to frontend JS object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, frontend

My controller is sending lat/lng data to my Handlebars view via res.render.

```
res.render('coords', viewModel);
```

'viewModel' contains an array of objects, with each object containing a name of a location, lat, and lng.  I want to take this information and plot markers on a Google map in my view. When I attempt to inject the data by way of Handlebars into an inline JS variable...

```
<script>
var viewMarkers = {{viewModel}};
console.log(viewMarkers);
</script>
```

I get this in my console...

```
<script>
var viewMarkers = [object Object],[object Object];
console.log(viewMarkers);
</script>
```

I'm only a beginner in the Node/Express realm and can't seem to comprehend how I can pass the viewModel data to the Google maps JS on the frontend.  My thought is that I would need to do an AJAX request to access the data. Regardless, I've scoured the Internet, but have not come across an example of this yet and could use some community guidance.

I appreciate any knowledge/assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must keep in mind that [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)' job is to return *Strings*. The mustache tags, `{{}}`, evaluate Object references as Strings so that the resultant text can be appended to the DOM or HTTP response body. The JavaScript inside your `<script>` tags does not get executed until it arrives on the client. There is no way for Handlebars to return an Object reference that could survive server-side rendering and eventually get assigned to a variable on the client.

`[object Object],[object Object]` is the result when an Array of two Objects is stringified (ie., it is the output of calling `console.log(String([{}, {}]));` in your browser's console.

In order to deliver JavaScript code to the client, you must construct your template to return a String with valid JavaScript in much the same way as a typical template returns valid HTML.

The long way of doing this would be something like the following:

```
<script>
    var viewMarkers = [
        {{#each viewModel}}
            {
                location: '{{location}}',
                lat: {{lat}},
                lng: {{lng}}
            }
            {{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
        {{/each}}
    ];
</script>
```

The simpler way of achieving this would be to have `JSON.stringify` do the work of stringifying your Array:

```
res.render('coords', { viewModel: JSON.stringify(viewModel) });
```

Then to render the JavaScript you would need only do the following in your template:

```
var viewMarkers = {{{viewModel2}}};
```

Note that we must use triple mustaches in order not to have our quotes [HTML-escaped](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping) by Handlerbars.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/zd8mmbh1/) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Oddly enough, I found that the objects contained 'undefined' in each of the fields (my bad) before I even left the controller.  Once that was fixed I was able to pass the normal, unstringified data with res.send to your <script> code in your post and Handlebars populated the viewMarkers array. Again, no stringifying, no Handlebar templates, nothing.  Based on your post, I didn't think that was possible; _italic_"There is no way for Handlebars to return an Object reference that could survive server-side rendering and eventually get assigned to a variable on the client."

Comment: @user2305363: I don't understand your comment. Are you saying that `var viewMarkers = {{viewModel}};` worked for you? If not, what did you do?

Comment: My apologies ... I sent the data like I normally do from the controller with the `res.render('coords', viewModel);` and then received viewModel in the frontend with your **exact** `script` block you posted above.  Handlebars is doing exactly what you said, returning Strings, so reconstructing the array of objects in the frontend by way of a #each worked like a charm.

Comment: @user2305363: OK. That's great! I misunderstood and thought you were saying my answer didn't work.