# Trying to pass a string variable to a javascript scope inside html using handlebars-express

Tags: javascript, html, express, express-handlebars

I am willing to pass a variable from server-side to client-side using handlebars-express, unfortunately to no avail.

Upon browsing the content here for quite some time, I may need assistance to sort it out.

Checked whether the object passed is of string type: Yes.
Tried couple of combinations of retrieving the data without success.

getDeviceID method below works as expected - checked to confirm that it returned the desired string.

authMe.js (router):

```
if (userInSystem) {
        var userDeviceID = await helpers.getDeviceID(usersSheetID, scope, Username);  
        res.render("signinSuccessful", { dID: userDeviceID });
 }
```

signinSuccessful.html:

```
<body>
    <script>
        var dID = '{{dID}}'; ///// -> 
        console.log(dID); //////// -> need elp with these two lines 
    </script>
    <div class="container-login100"></div>
    <script>signinSuccess()</script>
</body>
```

In app.js I have the following requirements:

```
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

It always prints '{{dID}}' even though I was under the impression this is the method of handling the string variable sent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This thread might be helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046510/how-to-pass-express-response-object-to-frontend-js-object)

Comment: unfortunately did not work, it keeps on printing what's inside the ' '

Answer (score 0):

I suffered a problem like this too where I had to pass in the values from a database into a client side script in my handlebars file and this didnt work. What I did was to save the value which I wanted in the client side script in the data-* attributes of some div which you can hide also if you want to like this

```
<div style="display:none;" data-value="{{dID}}" id="value"></div>
```

Than you can retrieve that value from the script using javascript or jquery
Using Javascript:

```
var dID = document.querySelector('#value').getAttribute('data-value');
```

Using JQuery:

```
var dID = $('#value').attr('data-value');
```

You can learn more about data-* attributes from this link 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: Hi @Usman, I tried both ways, still not working, as I get the dID = {{dID}} instead of dID. even tried to do the following: <div class="container-login100"></div>
    <div style="display:none;" data-value="{{dID}}" id="value"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dID = $('#value').attr('data-value');
            console.log(dID);
        });
    </script>

Comment: @Tom.A I have no idea on why it shouldn't work. I just checked my project and I have done the exact same thing.

Comment: Did you have the same definitions in app.js?

Comment: Earlier I was using hbs which is another module for handlebars. I installed express handlebars today and I havent checked it with that. Hmnn. Lemme check

Comment: @Tom.A I checked it right now and its still working

Comment: Oh. You are using html as an extension. How silly of me not to notice that. Change it to .handlebars

Comment: We have made a progress but still, getting Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "d:\nodejs-demo\views". unfortunately it seems it does not render hbs file. Can I maintain the signinSuccessfu file as hbs extension with the original html structure?

Comment: You have to use .handlebars extension. Or if you want to use .hbs extension you have to replace the exphbs setup with these three lines
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

Comment: Still does not work. I simply changed the extension to handlebars instead of html and all of a sudden it does not recognize it when requesting to render the page. adding the extension to the render did not work either.

Comment: Do you have it under the views folder?

Comment: Yes, can the hbs file keep the same structures as html?

Comment: Yes. Handlebars has the exact same structure as html may it be hbs, express-handlebars or any other handlebars related module.

Comment: Upload the folder on github or something. Lemme check whats wrong